# Add condition in seaboarn.countplot

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I have this `train_df[(train_df.Age < 30) & (train_df.Survived)].count() / train_df[(train_df.Age < 30)].count()`. This is the percentage of survived people under 30. How show in on graph with `seaboarn.countplot()`?

```
sns.countplot(x='Survived', data=train_df[(train_df.Age < 30) & (train_df.Survived)])
sns.countplot(x='Survived', data=train_df[(train_df.Age < 30)])
```

[image]

I want to see one common bar with two colors.

Comment: Could you please share what have you tried so far and what was the result? e.g. an error or a wrong plot ? That would help

Comment: @Phyast10 I try something like this `sns.countplot(x='Survived', data=train_df[(train_df.Age < 30) & (train_df.Survived)])
sns.countplot(x='Survived', data=train_df[(train_df.Age < 30)])` But it is not what I want.

Comment: You want to plot the percentage of people survived under the age 30 and this command should do it.  Can you show the plot and describe more what exactly is it that is needed.

Comment: @Phyast10 Update question.

Comment: If you don't need to use seaborn.countplot, you can use ```groupby('Survived')``` and use this dataframe, df to plot:  ```df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)```